# Bypass FRP lock, SM-T285

Tags: samsung, frp

One of our employees has had signed in with her Google account on a tablet (SM-T285, organizational one, and I didn't know that). Now she isn't here and we don't have access to her. Because she had had set a screen lock (and also many other customizations), I preferred to do a factory reset to make it totally clean. Now I am stuck in initial setup and need that Google account. How can I bypass this? I have googled a lot, no luck.

Thanks

**EDIT:** I have seen other posts, but none of them works for me. Connecting USB via OTG doesn't open explorer (Cable is OK). USB debugging disabled by default and no fastboot.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you checked with [other answered questions tagged `frp`](/search?q=[frp]+answers%3A1)? See e.g. [How to bypass “Verify your account” (Factory Reset Protection)](/q/127739/16575)

Comment: @Izzy I have editted. Please unmark my question as duplicate.

Comment: Please be aware that you must delete ALL Google accounts on Android, prior to doing a factory reset.

Comment: @Zillinium I know that, but in this case I haven't have done.

Comment: This may have been an expensive oversight.  Please try to make contact with the former employee, this should be your first action... If the employee has breached any terms of usage or contract by doing this, they may be liable for the "Damages" .. I understand that the device may not be physically damaged,, however it has been locked to her personal email account and therefore removed the ability of the entire devices usage... It is similar to me setting a bios administrator password on a work computer, to specifically render the motherboard useless.  I know you can reset the bios.. still...

Comment: @Zillinium We tried contacting her, no luck. Totally inaccessible.